# find all natural numbers satisfying condition

Tags: number-theory

There is natural number $n$ such that $n+1$ and $n-110$ are square of natural number. How to find $n$ ?

I tried to mark $n+1=k^2$ and $n-110=m^2$ and thats implies $k^2-m^2=111$ but I don't know how to find nautral solutions here

Comment: $k^2-m^2 = (k+m)(k-m)$. ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a hint. If $k^2-m^2=111$ you have $(k+m)(k-m)=1\cdot 111= 3\cdot 37$.

You haven't got a huge number of options to explore.

Comment: OK, thank you very much!